# Step into not working in the debugging mode Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I am working on a project of java. I opened the project in debugging mode, and goes through the program. One thing where I got stuck is that, if I step into a specfic function, it dont go into it. Instead if I put a breakpoint inside that function then program goes upto that point. I am using Eclipse 3.7.2. I dont know why eclipse is showing such a behaviour. Any help will be appreciaed.

Comment: It may be a dynamically created class. Are you using a framework like hibernate ?

Comment: Are you sure the code you're debugging is in sync with your source code? (This is usually only a problem if it's remote debugging).

Comment: It may be a problem too in Eclipse if the source isn't automatically refreshed and you link a separate project as well as an exported (jar) version.

Comment: I am using exported jar both in the build path as well as command line argument

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dystroy already said in a comment what I was planning to say in this answer: the most common cause for me experiencing this is when the actual runtime class instance is a dynamic proxy, usually from either hibernate, or Spring, or a mock object framework (when testing) such as Mockito.  In those cases, you generally have to do exactly what you have done, and put a breakpoint inside the method being stepped into.

Comment: Was this answer helpful in explaining things?